# convert char* to char &

Tags: c, char, base64, constants

I have the following code which is working fine:

```
//function1 for decoding base64
int base64_decode (const char *base64, char *to) { /*function*/ }

//code which is working
buf_struct tmpbuf;//structure
base64_decode(buffer, (char *)&tmpbuf);
```

and I wanted to convert it to avoid additional functions doing the same thing, into:

```
//function2 for decoding base64
char *unbase64(unsigned char *input, int length) { /*function*/ }

//code needs to be modified
buf_struct tmpbuf;//structure
char *unbase = unbase64(buffer, strlen(buffer));
unbase = (char *)&tmpbuf;
```

but the second one doesn't work.

***How can I convert "char *" to "(char *)&" ?***

EDIT:

```
char *unbase;
unbase = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
memset(unbase, 0, strlen(buffer) + 1);
//unbase = unbase64(buffer, strlen(buffer));
base64_decode(buffer, unbase);
fprintf(stderr,"unbase: %s\n",unbase);
strcpy((char *)&tmpbuf, unbase);
```

Comment: In second case what are you expecting from `tmpbuf`.?? What are you trying to do in function `unbase64`? `unbase` is assigned by return of `unbase64` then what are you assigning again on very next line?

Comment: I think you want to do it the other way around: `tmpbuf->.. = unbase;`. In the first example you should probably not cast `tmpbuf` to a `char *` but use a member of the `struct`, what is its definition?

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the data to the buffer:

```
//code needs to be modified
buf_struct tmpbuf;//structure
char *unbase = unbase64(buffer, strlen(buffer));
strcpy((char *)&tmpbuf, unbase);

// Depending on the contract for unbase64 you may need to free() unbase here.
```

Comment: I edited my post with the modified code but still doesn't work. I guess it's due '\n' between lines, but I'm not sure

Comment: In that case `base64_decode` and `unbase64` don't work the same way, but I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: thanks for your time and answer. I guess I will keep both functions after all.